# Meaning of Syntax for Ruby Module

Tags: ruby

I've been going through some tutorials to find this information, but haven't seen anything that directly addresses it.

I've seen several times on modules the following syntax:

```
module MyModule

   def run()
      puts "running"
   end
end
```

I've also seen syntax that looks like this:

```
module MyModule

   def MyModule.run()
      puts "running"
   end
end
```

What's the advantage to including the module name before the method and vice versa?

Comment: Have you tried calling the above code? It should be fairly obvious if you have.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have but I don't see the point other than making the essentially creating a namespace so that functions don't walk on one another.

Comment: in the second example you can call `MyModule.run`. Can you do the same in the first example?

Comment: @engineersmnky no I cannot.

Comment: It does, I understand how to directly call them, I'm just not sure when I should use one over the other. @engineersmnky

Comment: Things to research: classes, modules, self, singleton classes, the class Class and how classes themselves are objects.

Comment: The fist will allow you to mix this method into other classes e.g. `class A; include MyModule; end;` will allow you to call `A.new.run` and `class A; extend MyModule; end;` will allow you to call `A.run`.  In the second example the `run` method is bound to `MyModule` as the receiver and will have to be called as `MyModule.run`

Comment: @engineersmnky Makes perfect sense now. Thanks!

Comment: The second example looks very strange. Where did you see it?

Comment: The only (weird) use case I can think of is to alter constant lookup by defining the method in a module nested _within_ `MyModule`.

Comment: @Stefan I saw it here http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html

Comment: @CannonMoyer indeed and even some built-in Ruby classes use that syntax, for example [`Matrix`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/matrix.rb). Maybe because it resembles the way you invoke the methods. It still looks strange to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
module MyModule
   def MyModule.run()
      puts "running"
   end
end
```

is exactly the same as:

```
module MyModule
   def self.run()
      puts "running"
   end
end
```

Usually `def self.run` is used, because it's better when you have to change the module name and it's more idiomatic. I don't see any advantages in writing `def MyModule.run`.

Comment: "self" would be referring to a class where this module was used as a mixin, right?

Comment: `self` outside of an instance method definition refers to the module within `self` is.

Comment: @CannonMoyer within the body of the module, `self` and `MyModule` are identical.

Comment: "It's"? Which one is "it"? They're showing *two* versions.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with modules. This is just normal method definition syntax.

The syntax for a method definition in Ruby is

```
def <target>.<selector>(<parameters>)
  # …
end
```

For example:

```
def foo.bar(baz)
end
```

This will define a method named `bar` on the object referenced by `foo` (more precisely, in the singleton class of the object referenced by `foo`), with a single mandatory positional parameter whose binding is named `baz`.

Like with message sends, you can leave out the target, and Ruby will use an implicit default. In a message send, the implicit default is `self`, with a method definition, the default is the so-called *default definee*, which is *usually* the closest lexically enclosing module definition body.

So,

```
def MyModule.run
```

means "define a method named `run` on the object `MyModule` (or more precisely in the singleton class of the object `MyModule`)", whereas

```
def run
```

means "define a method named `run` in the default definee", i.e. the closest lexically enclosing module definition body, which in this case is `MyModule`.

The second version defines `run` as an *instance method* of `MyModule`, the first version defines `run` as an instance method of *the singleton class of* `MyModule`, which we sometimes call a "module method" or "module function".

Note that the first version is usually more idiomatically written as

```
def self.run
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about using a module as a static namespace vs using a module as a mixin. Have a look at the following code (with output in comments):

```
module MyModule

   def MyModule.run()
      puts "#{self}: running"
   end

   def run()
      puts "#{self}: running"
   end


end

class Foo
  include MyModule
end

MyModule.run #MyModule: running
foo = Foo.new
foo.run #<Foo:0x007f9b269bf028>: running
```

In the first usage, the module is basically just acting as a namespace to which you attach a method.
In the second, the module is *mixed in* to the class `Foo`. This means that it acts as if the `run` method was defined within the foo class in the first place; you could, if you wished, refer to instance variables `@bar` which aren't defined in the module, but only in the `Foo` class.

Comment: *"you could, if you wished, refer to instance variables @bar which aren't defined in the module, but only in the Foo class"* I would not recommend this part as this infers that the `Module` should have a more intimate knowledge than it should of the `Class` it is included in or visa versa. If you must use variables in this fashion they should be dependency injected into the the methods defined in the module e.g. `def run(arg=self); "#{arg}: running"; end` then `Foo` could call `run(@bar)`

Comment: Perhaps so- the OP just seemed fundamentally confused about the concept of a mixin, and I thought that this observation may help.

Answer (score -1):

I guess both are same but in case when we call module method inside class then we have to give

```
ModuleName.method_name()
```

So that it can understand that this method is required for included or that particular module

Comment: They are not the same at all (excepting the fact that is this simple example both contain the same method body)